# Why am I getting a syntax error for "except ValueError"

Tags: python-3.x

I keep on getting a syntax error for the line "except ValueError"

I tried many things including using 'pass' but it still didn't work.

```
y=0
while y==0:
    x= input ('Enter the time(hour) ')
    val = int(x)
    if val <0 or val >= 24:
        raise ValueError 
    break
except ValueError:
    pass
    print("Invalid integer. The number must be in the range of 0-24.")
    if val>=12:
        print (x + "pm")
    else:
        print (x + "am")
```

I wanted the program to return an error and print invalid integer if the 'val' was above or equal to 24 or lower than 0.

Comment: `except` makes no sense without a `try`...

Comment: oh wow ok, im new to python. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting a syntax error is that there is no valid standalone `except` statement. The correct usage of the except keyword is in a `try...except` statement.

```
y=0

while y==0:
    x= input ('Enter the time(hour) ')
    try:
        val = int(x)
        if val < 0 or val >= 24:
            raise ValueError 
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid integer. The number must be in the range of 0-24.")
        if val>=12:
            print (x + "pm")
        else:
            print (x + "am")
```

Above is your example altered to show the proper use of the `except` keyword.

Comment: if I do that ^, I don't get the desired outcome. It just asks me to input a number and the program ends. I do get the message "invalid integer" if the value I enter is above 24